# How to install multiple gulp packages at once using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I just switched to gulp task runner to automate my workflow, but there is this problem whenever i want to start a new project i have to install all packages required in gulpfile.js using the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev {package name}
```

Imagine there are 20 of them, it's a bit boring. How can simplify this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally I use mostly the same gulp plugins for all of my projects. I copy the `devDependencies` bit from the package.json of one of my previous projects into my newly created package.json, then I run `npm i` which installs all dependencies listed in `package.json`. It's a huge timesaver, especially since I usually copy my gulpfile.js as well.

Note: don't forget to run `npm outdated` if it's been a while since your previous project started, to check if any of the dependencies have been updated in the meantime.

Answer (score 44):

You can add multiple package names to npm install:

```
npm install --save-dev package1 package2 package3
```

npm will install and save the specified packages in your package.json.

Comment: I have packages in an array like var packs =["package1, package2, package3"] in this condition how can i install using node js ...var child =require('child_process').exec;
child= exec('npm install --save +packs,{
cwd:path
}

Comment: Use the Array.join function in exec. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 7):

You can also use brace expansion for installing many similarly named packages:

```
npm i -D babel-{core,preset-es2015,preset-react}
```